# ajax post method cause page reload with no postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm quite confused about the ajax/ASP POST behavior.
I have a form (the default one for the ASP pages) with an HTML button. With `jQuery` I do something in the click event, then I make an ajax POST call to a `WebMethod`:

```
<form runat="server" id="formRegistration" autocomplete="off" action="">
    ...other form controls
    <button id="btnSend" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
</form>

$("#btnSend").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // some validations

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        url: 'Default.aspx/Submit1',
        data: JSON.stringify(myData),
        contentType: "text/plain",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (msg) {
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
    return false;
});

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("IsPostBack = " + IsPostBack.ToString());
}

[WebMethod]
public static bool Submit1(string json)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json);
    return true;
}
```

- HTML button
- type = button
- return false

When I press the button it reloads the page, the `WebMethod` is not executed, instead the page is reloaded with... `IsPostBack = false`!

I just want to POST the string without reloading the page.

Comment: When you said your page is reloading it doesn't makes sense when you have a AJAX call. Does your $("#btnSend").click() being triggered correctly? Did you try placing some alerts ?

Comment: Yes, in that function I do other things, like validations, that actually work.

Comment: data: JSON stringify and dataType: "text" ?? replace your ajax call with this and try ..     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Default.aspx/Submit1',
        data: JSON.stringify(myData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });

Comment: I set those values because I'm sending a plain string, not a json object. If I would use your syntax I have to modify the Submit1 signature to receive all the json objects. And I don't want to do this.

Comment: No you don't need to change the signature of your method. Just replacing your Ajax call should do the magic.

Comment: I've already tried and I get a server error: `invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: json`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137582/discussion-between-sailor-and-mark).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a link instead a button, and change "form" to "div"

```
<a id="btnSend" type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Send</button>
```

Comment: Changing the `button` to `a` does nothing. I can't change `form` to `div` because it will prevent the ASP.NET page to run.

Comment: Ok, try adding onClientClick="return false;"

Comment: To the button properties

Comment: And change yout component to <asp:button

Comment: The `onClientClick` is not recommended in html5 and anyway does nothing. If I change the `button` to `asp:Button` it will run on server side and I cannot handle the click event in `jQuery`.

Comment: Actually, OnClientClick would works because you gona being saying to ASP that something is wrong("return false;"), so you do not want a PostBack, it's a like trick. And your OnClientClick once rendered on HTML5, does not will appear inside the html generated

Comment: I tried again. Even with `onClientClick="return false;"` the page is reloaded after the POST request.